# Python: Getting static properties via a property name

Tags: python, reflection, introspection, static-members

I have a python class with "emulated" static properties via a metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type):
   @property
   def x(self): return 'abc'

   @property
   def y(self): return 'xyz'


class My: __metaclass__ = MyMeta
```

Now some of my functions receives the property name as a string, which should be retrieved from My.

```
def property_value(name):
   return My.???how to call property specified in name???
```

The point here is that I don't want an instance of My to be created.

Many thanks,

Ovanes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
getattr(My,name)
```

Comment: Thanks I was sure having tried it and received an exception. But I tried it again and it works.... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this recently. I wanted to be able to write `Test.Fu` where `Fu` is a computed property.

The following works using a descriptor object:

```
class DeclareStaticProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.method(owner())

class Test(object):
    def GetFu(self):
        return 42
    Fu = DeclareStaticProperty(GetFu)

print Test.Fu # outputs 42
```

Note that there is an instance of `Test` allocated behind the scenes.